# How to stop Xbox from signing me out when I lose connection?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

Whenever my internet craps out (which is quite often), Xbox signs me out of my profile. This is extremely annoying and frustrating. I play offline games mostly too so I will always get sent back to the title screen when this happens. Can I stop it from signing out my profile when I loose connection?

Comment: ...How is it supposed to stay signed in when there's no connection? There's nothing it can do.

Comment: I'm talking about my profile not xbox live.

Comment: Xbox handles profiles weirdly, sometimes it'll log in my profile automatically and sometimes I have to log in myself by selecting my profile. I don't have my console here to check the options to assist you, but have you considered not connecting to live whilst playing singleplayer games?

Comment: That's a good point. Sometimes I like to switch between games and Netflix though. Thanks for the suggestion.